# Database locked error when creating SQLite DB using Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to create a new SQLite database on a device. The database appears "locked" and throws the following error:

```
13774-13774/com.example.dummy E/SQLiteLog: (5) database is locked
13774-13774/com.example.dummy E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.dummy/databases/quizdb'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
#################################################################
Error Code : 5 (SQLITE_BUSY)
Caused By : The database file is locked.
    (database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode)
```

I've stripped out what I think is irrelevant code to leave the following:

```
class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "quizdb";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 301;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String omPath = Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath();
        final String Path = omPath + "/data/com.example.dummy/databases/";
        SQLiteDatabase gg = null;

        try {
            gg=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Path + DB_NAME, null, 0);
        } catch (Exception e){
            //Database does not exist - need to create it
        sqlQuery = String.format("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s ( %s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s TEXT )", DB_TABLE, KEY_ID, KEY_QUES);

        db.execSQL(sqlQuery);
        addQuestions();
    }
}

    private void addQuestions() {
        Question q1 = new Question("Question1234");
        this.addQuestionToDB(q1, DB_TABLE);
    }

    private void addQuestionToDB(Question q, String DB) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, q.getQuestion());
        //Code fails on following line
        dbase.insert(DB, null, values);
    }
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: The error is triggered by the very last line of the code sample: 'dbase.insert(DB, null, values);'